# Cache Firebase user profile image - web sdk

Tags: firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase web hosting and Firebase real-time database for quick prototyping. Firebase provide a functionality to manage users into it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users I'm setting user profile image using below code

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

I want to cache this images, as this images takes too much time to load. I have added this lines to firebase.json to cache images in hosting.

```
"headers": [{
      "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)",
      "headers" : [{
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=3600"
      }]
    }]
```

So concluding that, Firebase is storing profile images into Storage bucket. Is there any way to cache storage files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storage caching refer to:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata

as you upload or at update you can set the meta-cache like so:

```
var Metadata = {
  cacheControl: 'public,max-age=36000',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}
```